# RestKit with enqueueBatchOfObjectRequestOperations

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I am trying to make 3 seperate reskit requests that gets a JSON response.

I can't find a clear answer on how to implement the restkit enqueueBatchOfObjectRequestOperations method.

Does anyone have some sample code that uses it?

I have 3 separate methods similar to this:

```
- (void)getRacks
{    


RKObjectMapping *deviceRackMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[DeviceRack class]];
[deviceRackMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                          @"id": @"deviceRackID",
                          @"dataCenterID": @"data_center_id",
                          @"number": @"deviceRackNumber",
                          }];

//Mapping of nested data center object
RKObjectMapping *dataCenterMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[DataCenter class]];
[dataCenterMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                          @"id": @"dataCenterID",
                          @"name": @"dataCenterName",
                          @"shortname": @"dataCenterShortName",
                                                            }];
[deviceRackMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"data_center"
                                                                          toKeyPath:@"dataCenter" 
                                                                                    withMapping:dataCenterMapping]];

    //Mapping of nested sites object
    RKObjectMapping *siteMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Site class]];
    [siteMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                      @"id": @"siteID",
                                                      @"name": @"name",
                                                      @"shortname": @"shortName",
                                                      }];
    [deviceRackMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"site"
                                                                                  toKeyPath:@"site"
                                                                                withMapping:siteMapping]];



    //Fetch array from JSON 
    RKObjectManager *objectManager3 = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    [objectManager3 getObject:self.deviceRacksArray
                        path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/v1/device_racks"]
                  parameters:nil
                     success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation3, RKMappingResult *mappingResult3)
                            {
                                self.deviceRacksArray = (NSArray *)[mappingResult3 array];
                            }
                     failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation3, NSError *error)
                            {
                                //errorMessageLabel.text = [error localizedDescription];
                                NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                            }];
}
```

I have 3 separate versions of this method and each get called in `viewDidLoad` by calling `[self getSites]`, The problem as I see it is that I have to queue up the requests. I can't find any sample code to show when and where I should be enqueueing the batch of object requests. I would settle for 3 separate connections, but it doesn't seem to allow that.

I call each of these methods before sending the arrays to a UIPickerView to be the datasource.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you be implementing it? You should pass a set of operations to it...

Comment: i've edited the question to better reflect what I am trying to do.

Comment: Do you have a requirement to queue them? Currently they will all run concurrently.

Comment: They don't run concurrently, only the first array is ever mapped.

Comment: They do run concurrently. Your problem is likely some clash between / error with your response descriptors. Not that your code currently shows any evidence of response descriptors existing - so that could be the problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an object manager then the easiest way to queue your requests is to get the `NSOperationQueue` from the `HTTPClient` of the object manager (`operationQueue`) and set the maximum number of concurrent operations.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I needed to add the mapping where the AFNetworking was called, and also needed to fix a small issue as to what to display in the pickerview row.